# How to keep in Camel all incoming messages from an external system

Tags: apache-camel, soap-client, interception

Dear Camel Riders!

I would like to ask you if you know about any recommended way how to keep / store all incoming messages from soap, rest, etc ...

Using current interceptors:

```
a) org.apache.camel.spi.InterceptStrategy
b) tag  interceptFrom
```

I have problem to distinguished, whether the incoming message is coming from the primary route (invoke by external client) or a nested route.

Also the class UnitOfWork method doesn't provide any access to the parent's originalInMessage, so within the processor I have difficulties, too.

Here is a small visual explanation what I want to achieve:
[image: The message flow]

Thanks for any suggestions,
Andrej

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mess with interceptors unless you are trying to refactor against an existing app with a lot of routes...

instead, just preserve the original message in an Exchange property or message header (along with any other message source properties, etc) and create a simple KEEP processor that retrieves the data, etc.

Comment: Helo Boda, thank you for your quick answer! Yes you are right, this is also possible solution, but the problems is that we do not want to use explicitly the KEEP processor within all incoming routes, because we expose our camel config to the customer, that might forget to specify it and than the impact is quite huge - A lost message and complains.... So do you see any other solution?

Comment: you can use interceptFrom() to apply to many routes w/o needing to explicitly modify them, but this will also need to be defined in the same CamelContext/RouteBuilder as the routes...so it would still be visible to your clients, etc.  only other option I can think of would be to proxy all requests (and log them) before sending to your client routes, etc...